# How to use $(this) to refer to a child in an on callback function

Tags: jquery

What selector do you use to refer to the child inside an `on` function? Sample is below.

```
$("#parent").on("click", $(this).find(".child"), function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

The `$(this)` that is being referred to in the console is the parent. How do I select the child? Note: Many children under parent, I only want to get `$(this)` as the child being clicked.

Comment: BTW, the second argument to `on` should be a selector, not a jQuery object.

Comment: The .child is not a direct child of #parent, that is why I chose a selector instead. If I bind it to the direct parent of .child, would $(this) refer to child instead of parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is:

```
$("#parent").on("click", ".child", function () {
    console.log($(this))  // this here refers to '.child' being clicked.
});
```

From [.on() API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> **selector**
>
> Type: String
>
> A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements
>   that will call the handler. If the selector is null or omitted, the
>   handler is always called when it reaches the selected element.

Comment: You only show him the correct syntax, but did not answer his question.

Comment: @vher2 With the correct syntax, the answer to his question is obvious.  It's also in the comment in the code.

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah I think you're right, maybe I only overlook it.

Comment: Its not a direct child so I would have to "find" the child. The $(this) refers to the #parent instead of ".child" in the code you placed.

Comment: `.on()` delegates the handler to all elements that match the selector that are within the elements the method is called on. They don't have to be direct children (often people write `$(document).on(...)` because they don't have a more specific element to use).

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I understood it better that way. My code works now. Thanks everyone for your response as well.

Comment: @PalashMondal From the documentation: _When jQuery calls a handler, the **this** keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; ... for delegated events this is an element matching **selector**._

Answer (score 0):

Instead of registering your handler on the parent node, you can register it on the children, as well:

```
$("#parent").children(".child").on("click", function() {
    // fires when any child of #parent is clicked; $(this) will be the child node clicked
});
```

Comment: I suspect the OP has a good reason to use `.on(type, child, handler)`.  The two are not equivalent.

Comment: I think he wants it on a specific child (hence the `.child` selector used with `.find()`), rather than on every single one of the "many children under parent".

Comment: @ajp15243 Might be. Though, `.children()` can also be provided a selector as argument to filter a node's children.

Comment: @Lukas Which I see you have edited into your answer, so my previous comment no longer applies.